# Can we use Laravel 5.7 email verification in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I have completed a project in laravel 5.6, i did't enable the email verification system yet. Now i want to enable the email verification system using [laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification) built-in email verification, i don't like to use any external API or Package for email verification. How can i use laravel 5.7 email verification in laravel 5.6?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to implement it yourself though. The built in email verification wasn't introduced until 5.7.

Comment: take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Comment: you have to upgrade your Laravel 5.7.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONjsvx63zc4

Comment: yes i upgraded it worked. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade Your Project 5.6 to 5.7

Just update your **laravel/framework** dependency to **5.7.*** in your **composer.json** file. Since you are upgrading from **5.6 to 5.7** then, you can easily just run composer update

And if you modified some of Laravel's **Traits** or **Methods** in your 5.6 application, then you can check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade for a more detailed info.As I know, Then you can enable the email verification system.